# Chart.js not resizing according to the change in container width

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am creating a dashboard that has multiple Chart.js. The dashboard has sidebar navigation which can be minimized when clicking the toggle button. Which increases the width of the container.

The chart does not fit its container to its height as you can see in the image.
[image]

but If I add CSS for the canvas tag it will use the height that is specified in the CSS. But its stretches the chart and makes it blury.
[image]

Also If I toggle the sidebar to minimize, the width of the chart increases but when I toggle to maximize the size of sidebar, the width of chart does not decrease according to the width of main container. As you can see, the dark part expanded outside the viewport.
[image]

HTML:

```
    <div class="graph1">
                    <div>
                        <h5>Profit & Loss (Column Grouped Chart)</h5>
                        <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Fuel Consumed (Litres)</h5>
                        <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5>Fleet Usage</h5>
                        <canvas id="myChart3"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.graph1 {
        position: relative;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
        height: 26rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;

        & > div {
            padding: 1rem;
            box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
            border-radius: 0.6rem;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 26rem;
        }
    }
```

JS:

```
/*Chart1*/
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Red'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
            },
        ],
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        // scales: {
        //  y: {
        //      beginAtZero: true,
        //  },
        // },
    },
});
```

Comment: I would show some code. Without it very difficult to say. What I would check is the maintainAspectRadio and responsive options of the charts and the aspect ratio attribute of the container :)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Code is updated. using ```maintainAspectRatio : false``` makes charts stretch vertically continuously to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

try adding this in your JS options:

```
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

Comment: example:       type: "line",
      data: this.data,
      options: {
        responsive:true,
        maintainAspectRatio:false,